# Connecting Onedrive to webpage

Tags: php, onedrive

I have a MS- Onedrive business account. I need to connect my onedrive to my webpage, to view folders, download files, etc. How can I intergrage Onedrive with my webpage using PHP? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The OneDrive File picker might be your best bet if you simply want to get list of files, folder location, and downloand/update files from OneDrive.  This uses the JavaScript API so you'll need to incorporate that into your site.  Setup is pretty simple.  Register your application at https://account.live.com/developers/applications to get important info to authenticate/authorize the user and make calls to the service (i.e. client_id, client_secret, etc.) then take a look at the sample code at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659733.aspx.  If this is for OneDrive for Business, you want to look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they have an API for PHP, you might have to use JavaScript if you want to follow an API. Have a look at [this](http://onedrive.github.io/index.htm).

You can still use PHP but you will have to build it from zero. Take advantage of the HTTP requests, click [here](http://onedrive.github.io/README.htm).

[Here](https://github.com/lovattj/php-skydrive) is an example in PHP for the old name Skydrive

Comment: Thanks a lot Andre. I have visited this URL http://onedrive.github.io/README.htm .but i cannot understand hos to start.Could you please give me any sample code ? My requirement is : When i click on a button i want to access to my one drive .I have a email address & password only of onedrive

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the [OneDrive SDK for PHP](https://github.com/krizalys/onedrive-php-sdk). It's GPLed, supporting the latest OneDrive specifications, and the API is straightforward to get started within minutes.

Have a look at the examples provided and/or comments in the source code for some examples.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Comment: Can you explain why PHP 5.6 is the minimum requirement and if I try to use it with PHP 5.5. would it just not work at all, or would only a specific feature not work?  Just asking because an upgrade in PHP may not be possible but I'm wondering if your library would still mostly work with PHP 5.5.