# Query from an Online Excel (Eg;OneDrive) using PHP

Tags: php, sql, excel, html

I am trying to create a basic Tracking system on a wordpress site. My plan is to query from online excel (on onedrive) using PHP. But i am not sure how to connect my web app to an online excel to query similar to a database. Could anyone please help me on this

Comment: You really need to show the community what research you have done. Is this any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602468/excel-file-manipulation-via-php (indeed, googling PHP excel manipulation comes up with quite a few possibilities)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's possible. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737447/connecting-onedrive-to-webpage) might have some useful information about that.

Looking around, it turns out [there might be an API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33853882/10957435), but the person who suggested it claims to have wrote it too, so make of that what you will.